# Recover from crash with a core dump

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

A C++ program crashed on FreeBSD 6.2 and OS was kind enough to create a core dump. Is it possible to amputate some stack frames, reset the instruction pointer and restart the process in gdb, and how?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to amputate some stack frames, reset the instruction pointer and restart the process in gdb?

I assume you mean: change the process state, and set it to start executing again (as if it never crashed in the first place).

No. For one thing, how do you propose GDB (if it magically had this capability) would handle your file descriptors (which the kernel automatically closed when your process died)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken GDB has ability to call functions and assign variables, so at least in theory it is possible to reinstate file descriptors at a point in which process restarts.

Comment: "Has ability to call functions" -- only if you have a "live" inferior process. When you debug core, GDB can't. "Reinstate file descriptors": they could have been pointing into files that no longer exist, or to sockets. Also, file offset is maintained only by the kernel, so GDB has no way of restoring them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gdb can debug core dumps just as well as running programs.  Assuming that `a.out` is the name of your program's executable and that `a.core` is the name of your core file, invoke gdb like so:

```
gdb a.out a.core
```

And then you can debug like normal, except you cannot continue execution in any way (even if you could, the program would just crash again).  You can examine the stack trace, registers, memory, etc.

Comment: GDB does not debug core dumps "just as well as running programs", as you can't execute any printers.  See http://yosefk.com/blog/very-funny-gdb-ve-ery-funny.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this: [Best practices for recovering from a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401689/best-practices-for-recovering-from-a-segmentation-fault/12824168#12824168)

Summary: It is possible but not recommended. The way to do it is to usse setjmp() and longjmp() from a signal handler. (Please look at complete source code example in duplicate post.